# Python smtplib Name or service not known

Tags: python, email, smtp, gmail

i was making a simple daemon in python which takes a mail queue and delivers them to the recipients. Everything is working pretty good except from the `smtplib` which is actually the most important part.

## What happens?

When im running the script im getting the following error:

```
root@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/mailer/tests# python daemon_run.py
[Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

From what i found on the internet this error occurs when it cant connect to the SMTP server. Most users suggested fixes on postman which i dont use since i take advantage of google's services.

## The code

```
headers = "\r\n".join(["from: " + "my_email@gmail.com",
                        "subject: " + "Testing",
                        "to: " + "recipient@gmail.com",
                        "mime-version: 1.0",
                        "content-type: text/html"])

content = headers + "\r\n\r\n" + template_content

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.google.com', 587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login('my_email@gmail.com', 'pass')
server.sendmail('my_email@gmail.com', 'recipient@gmail.com', content)
server.close()
```

Please note that i'm using exactly the same login details in PHPMailer which actually works.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's `smtp.gmail.com` , not google.

Comment: Also consider using a timeout: server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587, timeout=30)

Comment: @PauloAlmeida I'm stupid. I spend 2 hours searching for this.....

Comment: @TrisNefzger i will. thanks for tettling me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the goold old typo hit again. Gmail's SMTP is `smtp.gmail.com` and not `smtp.google.com`